# Привязка в UWP, обращение к Parent

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, binding, bind

Добрый день. Есть ListView с забинженным к нему ObservableCollection:

```
<ListView Margin="0,0,0,30"  x:Name="ListViewPreview" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Shapes, Mode=OneWay}">                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="120" Height="120" Background="#484848" Tapped="Grid_Tapped" Padding="0">
                        <Image Width="120" Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding}" Stretch="UniformToFill">
                        </Image>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

ObservableCollection:

```
public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> Shapes = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
```

Так вот, если обращаться к ListView, то элементом является BitmapImage, а как получить Grid? То есть я хочу изначально Grid первого элемента покрасить в другой цвет, но не знаю как к нему обратиться.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте присоединяемое свойство зависимости. Сделайте класс с полями BitmapImage и Color (SolidColorBrush). И через свойство зависимости привязывайтесь к свойству Color.

Answer (score 0):

Можно менять шаблон первого элемента через ItemTemplateSelector.